# How to update a dictionary in python with another dictionary to a specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries in python, one contains three keys and one with one key. One of the key is common to both of the dictioaries but have different data within the key. I want to update that one key to the dictionary with the three keys. The one key have to replace the existing key from the other dictionary. I dont know how to do that! dictionary.update() works but it repeats the key rather than replacing. 
Here is my code:

```
    orders = {}
    orders2 = {}
    orders[int(code)] = str(name),int(current_stock),int(re_order),int(target_stock),float(price)
    orders2[str(user_code)] = str(orders[user_code][0]), new_stock, orders[user_code][2], str(orders[user_code][3]), str(orders[user_code][4])
```

Now i want to update orders2 into orders but if one of the "user_code" from the orders2 matches the "code" in orders, then rather than just updating it into the code, i want to replace that whole key with "orders2"

PS: These dictionaries are from a .txt file and in this file there are 3 different codes, its up to the user to determine the key in "orders2".

IF further information needed about the code please ask. Thank you!

FIRST OUTPUT IS:

{56756777: ('100 mm bolts', 15, 5, 40, 0.2), 34512340: ('plain brackets', 20, 5, 35, 0.5), 90673412: ('L-shaped brackets', 16, 5, 45, 1.2)}

THE SECOND OUTPUT IS(MAY VARY):

{'34512340': ('plain brackets', 10, 5, '35', '0.5')}

SO i want to replace the "34512340" key

```
     orders.update(orders2)
        print(orders)
```

This print(orders):

{56756777: ('100 mm bolts', 15, 5, 40, 0.2),

'34512340': ('plain brackets', 10, 5, '35', '0.5'),

34512340: ('plain brackets', 20, 5, 35, 0.5),

90673412: ('L-shaped brackets', 16, 5, 45, 1.2)}

### You see those two "34512340" repeated, i want it to replace it.

I wanted to ask this as well as i cant post anymore in 90 minutes:

I have a dicionray which i want to write all the data to a .txt file.
I want the data to be in line by line according to the key.
The .txt file already have some data which i want to DELETE.

```
    print(orders) #This is my dictionray (This can be varied)

    {56756777: ('100 mm bolts', 15, 5, 40, 0.2), 34512340: ('plain brackets', 10, 5, '35', '0.5'), 90673412: ('L-shaped brackets', 16, 5, 45, 1.2)}
```

I want to write all of this in the .txt file (which i called 'items.txt') by the key. For example:

i want the key "56756777" which contains: "56756777: ('100 mm bolts', 15, 5, 40, 0.2)" to be in one line like this:

56756777,100 mm bolts, 15, 5, 40, 0.2

Seprated by commas for other 2 keys too

Thank you, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of the two dictionaries and the expected output? E.g. `{ 'foo': 9 }` and `{ 'foo': 3, 'bar': 5, 'baz': 8 }` should produce `{ 'foo': 9, 'bar': 5, 'baz': 8}`. (I'm not sure if that's what you actually want. That's the reason I'm asking. :-P)

Comment: (For the example I gave above, `dict.update` works fine.)

Comment: "dictionary.update() works but it repeats the key": I have never seen that happen. Are you dictionaries normal `dict`s, and are you keys *exactly* the same (not a `str` that looks like an `int`, e.g., `"1"` when printed shows as `1`)?

Comment: Where is `dict.update()` used in your code? Please make a short, self-contained example that we can test. Not code for which we don't have the data (`new_stock`, `current_stock` variables), or that doesn't show the problematic behaviour.

Comment: I updated some of the examples

Comment: @SpeedDemo Looks like the issue is that the second dictionary has `'34512340'` as a key (a string), and the first dictionary has `34512340` as a key (an int). If you make them both the same type, `dict.update` should work fine for you.

Comment: Thank you so much smarx, it worked

Answer (score 1):

This is the reply from smarx:

"@SpeedDemo Looks like the issue is that the second dictionary has '34512340' as a key (a string), and the first dictionary has 34512340 as a key (an int). If you make them both the same type, dict.update should work fine for you. – smarx 3 mins ago"

Thank you it worked